# Событие изменения свойства объекта

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь реализовать в объекте нечто наподобие события для реакции на изменение его свойства:

```
obj = {
    prop: -1,
    onChange: function() {},
    setProp: function(value) {
        this.prop = value;
        this.onChange;
    }
}
```

И далее, в основном коде скрипта:

```
function func() {
    код
}
...
obj.onChange = func;
```

Такой метод не работает. Думаю, я что-то делаю не так, с подобными событиями раньше не работал. Как это обычно делается?

Comment: `this.onChange();` - чтобы вызвать, добавьте скобочки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.onChange();` - чтобы вызвать, добавьте скобочки

Используйте один метод с разным числом параметров для `get`/`set`:

```js
var obj = {
    _prop: -1,
    onChange: null,
    prop: function() {
        if (arguments.length == 0)
            return this._prop;
    
        this._prop = arguments[0];
        if (this.onChange)
            this.onChange();
    }
};

obj.onChange = function() { console.log("onChange handler"); }
console.log(obj.prop());
obj.prop(3);
console.log(obj.prop());
```